# How to navigate between nodes in JavaFX?

Tags: javafx, nodes, keyboard-events

I have a search box in my JavaFX application that searches content from a database and returns the details as nodes. I want to be able to go up and down between the returned nodes with the keyboard up and down keys. How can I achieve this functionality in JavaFX?

Search method

```
public void getText(KeyEvent event) throws IOException {
        // Testing
        TextFields.bindAutoCompletion(searchArea1, "Test1", "Test2", "Test3");

        // Getting search keywords
        String text = searchArea.getText();


        // Connecting to database
        DatabaseMySQL db = new DatabaseMySQL();
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("layouts/song-view.fxml"));
        loader.load();

        scrlpneSong.setVisible(true);
        scrlpneSong.setContent(vboxSong);

        Task<List<Songs>> task = new Task<>() {
            @Override
            protected java.util.List<Songs> call() throws Exception {
                return db.searchSongDetailsBySongName(text);
            }
        };

        task.setOnSucceeded(e -> {
            List<Songs> songList = task.getValue();
            Node[] nodes;
            nodes = new Node[songList.size()];
            vboxSong.getChildren().clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
                try {
                    nodes[i] = FXMLLoader.load(Objects.requireNonNull(getClass().getResource("layouts/search-song.fxml")));
                    Label lblSongName = (Label) nodes[i].lookup("#searchResultSongName");
                    Label lblISRC = (Label) nodes[i].lookup("#searchResultISRC");
                    Label lblArtist = (Label) nodes[i].lookup("#searchResultArtist");
                    lblSongName.setText(songList.get(i).getSongName());
                    lblISRC.setText(songList.get(i).getISRC().trim());
                    lblArtist.setText(songList.get(i).getSinger().trim());
                    vboxSong.getChildren().add(nodes[i]);

                } catch (NullPointerException | IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            KeyCode keyCode = event.getCode();
            if (keyCode == KeyCode.DOWN) {
                // vboxSong.requestFocus();
                ObservableList<Node> children = vboxSong.getChildren();
                children.getFirst().requestFocus();
                // Node node = children.get(pressCount[0]);

                // System.out.println(pressCount[0]);
                // node.requestFocus();
            } else if (keyCode == KeyCode.ENTER) {
                ObservableList<Node> children = vboxSong.getChildren();
                Node node = children.get(pressCount[0]);
                node.requestFocus();
            }
        });

        Thread thread = new Thread(task);
        thread.start();
    }
```

search-details.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.Cursor?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<VBox fx:id="mainVBox" prefWidth="696.0" spacing="10.0" styleClass="white-background" stylesheets="@../styles.css" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/20.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.example.song_finder_fx.UIController">
   <Label text="Search Song Details">
      <font>
         <Font name="Segoe UI Semibold" size="28.0" />
      </font>
      <VBox.margin>
         <Insets left="30.0" top="30.0" />
      </VBox.margin>
   </Label>
   <Label layoutX="41.0" layoutY="115.0" text="Audios">
      <VBox.margin>
         <Insets left="31.0" top="30.0" />
      </VBox.margin>
      <font>
         <Font name="Segoe UI Semibold" size="12.0" />
      </font>
   </Label>
   <VBox fx:id="vBoxInSearchSong" maxWidth="606.0" minWidth="600.0" prefWidth="606.0" styleClass="textarea-bg" stylesheets="@../styles.css">
      <VBox.margin>
         <Insets left="30.0" right="30.0" />
      </VBox.margin>
      <HBox styleClass="search-container" stylesheets="@../styles.css">
         <VBox.margin>
            <Insets left="30.0" right="30.0" top="30.0" />
         </VBox.margin>
         <padding>
            <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
         </padding>
         <TextField fx:id="searchArea" onKeyPressed="#getText" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="500.0" promptText="Enter song name">
            <font>
               <Font size="14.0" />
            </font>
            <HBox.margin>
               <Insets />
            </HBox.margin>
         </TextField>
         <ImageView fitHeight="20.0" fitWidth="20.0" onMouseClicked="#getText" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
            <HBox.margin>
               <Insets left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
            </HBox.margin>
            <cursor>
               <Cursor fx:constant="HAND" />
            </cursor>
            <Image url="@../images/icon%20_search%20normal%201_.png" />
         </ImageView>
         <TextField fx:id="searchArea1" layoutX="16.0" layoutY="16.0" onKeyPressed="#getText" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="500.0" promptText="Enter song name">
            <font>
               <Font size="14.0" />
            </font>
         </TextField>
      </HBox>
      <ScrollPane fx:id="scrlpneSong" prefHeight="320.0" prefWidth="544.0" styleClass="scroll-pane" stylesheets="@../styles.css" vbarPolicy="ALWAYS" visible="false">
         <VBox.margin>
            <Insets bottom="30.0" left="30.0" right="30.0" />
         </VBox.margin>
         <VBox fx:id="vboxSong" onKeyPressed="#onSearchedSongPress" prefWidth="525.0" styleClass="search-results-pane" stylesheets="@../styles.css" />
      </ScrollPane>
   </VBox>
</VBox>
```

search-song.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<VBox fx:id="vboxSongSearch" onKeyPressed="#onSearchedSongPress2" onMouseClicked="#onSearchedSongClick" prefWidth="183.0" styleClass="search-result" stylesheets="@../styles.css" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/20.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.example.song_finder_fx.UIController">
    <padding>
        <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="30.0" top="10.0" />
    </padding>
    <HBox prefHeight="50.0">
        <ImageView fitHeight="50.0" fitWidth="50.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
            <Image url="@../images/Green%20Gradient.jpg" />
        </ImageView>
        <VBox>
            <HBox.margin>
                <Insets left="20.0" top="2.5" />
            </HBox.margin>
            <Label fx:id="searchResultSongName" text="Song Name">
                <font>
                    <Font size="14.0" />
                </font>
            </Label>
            <HBox>
                <VBox.margin>
                    <Insets top="5.0" />
                </VBox.margin>
                <Label fx:id="searchResultISRC" text="ISRC" />
                <Label layoutX="10.0" layoutY="10.0" text=" | " />
                <Label fx:id="searchResultArtist" layoutX="10.0" layoutY="10.0" text="Artist" />
            </HBox>
        </VBox>
    </HBox>
</VBox>
```

Comment: It looks like you are trying to re-invent a lot of built-in functionality here. Consider replacing the scroll pane and `VBox` with a `ListView<Song>` and refactoring `search-song.fxml` as part of a `ListCell<Song>`. The `ListView` already comes with a selection model, keyboard navigation, scrolling, etc.

Comment: The problem with using a list view is I cannot customize the list items I think. @James_D

Comment: Why can’t you customize them?

Comment: Is there a way to add FXML to a ListView item? like I did with nodes? @James_D